# Arduino Ethernet failing to initialize correctly

Tags: http, initialization, arduino, ethernet

When the code [HERE](http://pastebin.com/DtLiUnuE)(Edit: Wrong code :) is used, the Serial monitor is spammed with this:
http://pastebin.com/nsD4CALFg
I cannot find any problems with the code, and it is a long one...
EDIT2: It now spams this http://pastebin.com/BXfFFBKHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what was wrong(Sort of)... There was a bug with that specific program, because I copied the exact same program into an empty one and it worked :L...